# Is it possible to have a div on a site that does not effect the body scroll bars?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have my website that is 1000px wide and centered. I have a div, inside the centered 1000px div, that is 500px left and 700px width. The div overflows out of the 1000px div to the right by 200px.

Everything looks great but on smaller monitors the overflowing div creates a scroll bar on the bottom.

Is it possible to mark this overflowing div as something like "do not add to scrollable area"?

I only want the overflowing part of this div to be visible if there is enough room on the screen.

**Added a Picture to help describe the issue.

**[Added js fiddle here](http://bit.ly/1g3qa9E) << had to use bit.ly cause it won't let me post jsfiddle

[image]

Comment: The code of the website is very complex and contains too much stuff not relevant to the question. I have added an image to help explain the issue.

Comment: Cut the code you want to show. Make a demo in jsfiddle and be sure someone will very fast give an answer.

Comment: jsfiddle has been posted: http://jsfiddle.net/HXge2/12/

Answer (score 0):

You should use height and width in percentage. By using this it will work on every resolution and div never get scrolled.
Like

```
div.body{
   width: 100%
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Could you let me know what is exactly your HTML DOM structure?

Comment: Sorry. I have now added an image to further explain the issue that I am asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your overflowing div. Anything that spills out of the div will not show in smaller monitors.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Sorry. I have now added an image to further explain the issue that I am asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:visible;` to the div with `1000px` width. This will make the portion of the `700px` width div to extend to right over the yellow div.

To prevent the scrollbar give `overflow:hidden;` to the body tag. But if the screen width is less than 1200px, the right portion will get cut. Try this anyway.